# Difference between audit and debounce in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

I am reading the official documentation of RxJS and then I realized they both are doing exactly the same thing.

To me they both seem exactly similar.

Please point out the difference between them if there is any at all.

Comment: I disagree with closing them, it seems like a fine question

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I'm going to describe the difference between them in terms of their `Time` versions as that's how I understand them best.

Both `auditTime` and `debounceTime` will initially start a timer when an event comes in. Both will wait the given amount of time before they emit an event. The difference is that `debounceTime` resets the timer whenever a new event comes in while `auditTime` does not. `auditTime` will emit the most recent event after the given number of milliseconds whether or not it is still receiving events. `debounceTime` will wait for a gap in the events. You said you read the documentation but just to double check I have found [this](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) document particularly helpful.

Comment: that help me alot

Comment: So turns out `auditTime` is same as `throttleTime` with `{ leading: false, trailing: true }` config parameter.

Answer (score 52):

Heres a marble diagram to compare the `*Time` counterparts:

[image: debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime]

Each value here represents time of its emission.

Play with this marble diagram here: **[debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/debounceTime-vs-throttleTime-vs-auditTime-vs-sampleTime/)**

And here is a more in-depth review: [RxJS debounce vs throttle vs audit vs sample | dev.to](https://dev.to/kosich/debounce-vs-throttle-vs-audit-vs-sample-difference-you-should-know-1f21)

*Already having an awesome answer by @qfwfq, I wanted to add a more visual explanation.*

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

[auditTime vs sampleTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BcGA.png)

This is about auditTime and sampleTime difference.
mabey you can use this img to understand the difference.

Comment: Doesn't kos' answer from four years ago already cover this?