# RxJS - Emit only after specific delay of idleness

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a form where the user can enter markdown-formatted text in a textarea. I'd like to show a *quasi live* preview of the *parsed* markdown next to the field.

Exactly like the StackOverflow question form. ;-)

The values of the textarea are being emitted through an RxJS Observable but I don't want to refresh the preview for every new value. Instead I'd like to refresh the preview **only after the user has stopped typing for say 500ms**.

Here's a tentative diagram (first line is the raw values emitted by the textarea as the user types, second line is what I'd like to obtain; **a value is emitted only once a specific delay WITH NO EMISSION has elapsed**):

```
t---t--ttt------tt-ttt------t---|
----------------t-----------t---|
```

What would be the syntax to achieve this?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: JB... Could it be as simple as that? :)

Comment: It can. You can also chain it with distinctUntilChanged(), to avoid recomputing the HTML if the user, for example, adds two characters and deletes them.

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly for asking. I read a bunch of tutorials where they show you how to build an autocomplete field with RxJS using the `debounceTime()` operator and here I am asking this question... I'll leave it here for future reference. I'll mark it as answered if you're willing to post an answer.

Comment: That happens to all of us, sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [debounceTime() operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime).

You can also chain it with `distinctUntilChanged()`, to avoid recomputing the HTML if the user, for example, adds two characters and deletes them

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **auditTime** for your use case in terms of UX.

If the user is typing continuously , then using **debounceTime** , the Quasi Preview wouldn't generate until there is a pause.

However, in **auditTime**, the Quasi Preview is generated for every time interval as long as there is a type event.

I believe **auditTime** gives a better UX.

> Both auditTime and debounceTime will initially start a timer when an
>   event comes in. Both will wait the given amount of time before they
>   emit an event. The difference is that debounceTime resets the timer
>   whenever a new event comes in while auditTime does not. auditTime will
>   emit the most recent event after the given number of milliseconds
>   whether or not it is still receiving events. debounceTime will wait
>   for a gap in the events. You said you read the documentation but just
>   to double check I have found this document particularly helpful.

Some references which I found useful.

https://medium.com/@jvdheijden/rxjs-throttletime-debouncetime-and-audittime-explained-in-examples-c393178458f3

[Difference between audit and debounce in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184789/difference-between-audit-and-debounce-in-rxjs)